# Get selected image from FlowPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm looking for a way to get selected Node from a FlowPane:

```
public class MainApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // First FlowPane

        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        flow.setColumnHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
        flow.setPrefWrapLength(200);
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            flow.getChildren().add(new Label(String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        flow.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event) {
                // Get selected image
            }

        });


        // Second FlowPane

        FlowPane secFlow = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        secFlow.getChildren().add(<selected image>);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

In my case I want to get from FlowPane using ContextMenu Node which I would like to insert into second FlowPane. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is no general notion of selection - so what exactly do you mean by "selected" image?

Comment: The node that I have clicked on with mouse.

Comment: okay, then you need logic that keeps track of that node: in your mouse handler, store the node that's clicked and in the contextMenu item, do something with the stored node

Comment: I.e. register mouse handlers with (or just set context menus on) each node, instead of registering one with the `FlowPane`